# How to return an object from parent class with type of Impl class?

Tags: java

I want to provide all implementation classes a default method that initializes the parent fields with default values. So I don't have to redefine those initialization within each Impl class:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    private String name;

    public static Parent defaultParent() {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        //fill default field values
        parent.name = "default name";
        return parent;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {

}
```

Now I can call `Child.defaultParent()`. But that would return me an object of type `Parent`. Is it possible this way to having the object being a `Child` object implicit? So that the `defaultParent` method always returns a type of the implementation class?

Maybe with java 8, functional interfaces or similar?

Comment: but...why won't you use constructor ?

Comment: Because a constructor would initialize the fields always. I usually don't want them to be initialized, just in certain cases where I call `defaultParent()`.

Comment: But this way, you are initializing separate object. If You want to initialize fields of parent in class hierarchy You have to use standard construction path.

Comment: Why not overload the constructor?

Comment: @endriu_l I'd be fine initializing a separate object, but it then should be of type `Child`.

Comment: @shmosel could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with Java 8:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    private String name;

    public static <T extends Parent> T defaultParent(Supplier<T> constructor) {
        T parent = constructor.get();
        //fill default field values
        parent.name = "default name";
        return parent;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {

}
```

You can call the static method like this:

```
Child c = Parent.defaultParent(Child::new);
```

Or you can just use a constructor overload instead of a static factory method:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    private String name;

    public Parent(boolean useDefaults) {
        if (useDefaults) {
            //fill default field values
            this.name = "default name";
        }
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(boolean useDefaults) {
        super(useDefaults);
    }

    public Child() {
        super(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Great!

Answer (score 1):

This is what constructors were made for.

```
abstract class Parent {
    private String name;
    protected Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    protected Parent() {
        this("default name");
    }
}
class DefaultChild extends Parent {
   public DefaultChild() { super(); }
}
class CustomChild extends Parent {
   public CustomChild(String value) { super(value); }
}
```

Everything else is just a fancy init method which is inferior to constructors because you can for example no longer assign values to `final` fields.

```
abstract class Parent {
    private String name;
    protected void init() {
        this.name= "default name";
    }
    // or
    protected static void init(Parent parent) {
        parent.name = "default name";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, though I like the idea of an `init` method in the parent. This way I could call `new Child().initDefault()` at will, having all default fields initialized. Without java 8 functions.